# Why does the scythe have a cooldown bar? Does it have a hidden ability?

Tags: stardew-valley

When I use my weapons ability (in my case blocking with my sword) the red cooldown bar appears on my weapon *and* my scythe.

The scythe doesn't have an ability though, right? Is there something I'm missing about it? Why does it have a cooldown bar?

Comment: Opening this, as it seems to be asking about a game mechanic, not dev intent. Please see [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15062/how-can-it-be-determined-whether-a-question-speculates-about-developer-intent/15066#15066) if you disagree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because all "swords" (as considered by the game) share the same cooldown (same with all hammers and/or daggers too). Yes, the scythe is just a sword with a strange sprite that is also flagged as a tool. They have a damage value, crit chance, everything just like a normal weapon.

Probably because it is flagged as a tool, the right-click ability and the Forge are disabled for the scythe, though. It has no special weapon ability but other tool-related ones (harvest some crops like kale and amaranth, and get hay from grass if you have a silo built).

Answer (score 2):

There is no gameplay reason why this happens, and it makes no difference whether your scythe is on cooldown or not. Most likely, it is a programming artifact that is hard to fix, and it's probably not worth working on if it doesn't affect the gameplay in any way.